# Get Value from Combobox / Apply report filter to a pivot table with VBA

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table, vba

I have an user form,where users selects the domain from a combobox(cboCountry) and according to this selection I am trying to apply a filter to an existing pivot table with VBA. My code is like below, but however, this code is not working.

I would appreciate it if someone could help me with this code.

```
Dim chartType As String
chartType = cboCountry.Value

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Domain")
.Orientation = xlPageField
.Position = 1
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Domain").ClearAllFilters
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Domain").CurrentPage = chartType
```

I have the following error.

```
Run-time error '1004':

Application-defined or object-defined error
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the value of `cboCountry.Value`? Also try `Trim(cboCountry.Value)` as well

Comment: Thank you , it works perfect with Trim(cboCountry.Value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trimming the value of the combobox fixed the problem.

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Domain")
.Orientation = xlPageField
.Position = 1
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Domain").ClearAllFilters
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Domain").CurrentPage = Trim(cboCountry.Value)
```